# Jackson serialization XML with root to abstract class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an application and I need to serialize XML with different tags at the root level.

I implemented a test case with the following scenario, through the same input I get both xmls.

```
<ClassTypeA>
    <fieldA>a</fieldA>
</ClassTypeA>
```

and

```
<ClassTypeB>
    <fieldB>b</fieldB>
</ClassTypeB>
```

To serialize I implemented these three classes:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteDisconnectXML.class, name = "ClassTypeA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteConnectXML.class, name = "ClassTypeB"),
})
abstract class TestXml{

}

@Getter
@Setter
class TestConcreteDisconnectXML extends TestXml{
    private String fieldA;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class TestConcreteConnectXML extends TestXml{
    private String fieldB;
}
```

using this test below the following error is returned:

```java
    public void testDeserializeXML() throws Exception {

        objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        
        
        String message = "<ClassTypeA>\n" +
                "\t<fieldA>a</fieldA>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeA>";

        TestXml cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);

        message = "<ClassTypeB>\n" +
                "\t<fieldB>b</fieldB>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeB>";

        cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);


    }
```

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'fieldA' as a subtype of `br.com.eletra.filemode.uaa.converter.TestXml`: known type ids = [ClassTypeA, ClassTypeB]
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 2, column: 2]
```

However, when inserting any tag at the beginning of the structure, serialization is successful.

[image]

I`ve made another test with the jackson 2.12 with deduction type.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ClassTypeA.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(ClassTypeB.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(DefaultClass.class),
})
abstract class TestXml{

}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class ClassTypeA extends TestXml{
    private String fieldA;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class ClassTypeB extends TestXml{
    private String fieldB;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class DefaultClass extends TestXml{

}
```

but a null error without details was thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil.sanitizeXmlTypeName(StaxUtil.java:81)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlTypeResolverBuilder.typeProperty(XmlTypeResolverBuilder.java:45)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlTypeResolverBuilder.typeProperty(XmlTypeResolverBuilder.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector._findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:1517)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findTypeResolver(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:572)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findTypeResolver(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:236)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findTypeDeserializer(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1754)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:597)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4731)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4592)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3546)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3514)
    at br.com.eletra.filemode.uaa.converter.XmlConvertTest.testDeserializeXML(XmlConvertTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:177)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:241)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Any suggestion to implement something like this, without insert a tag into the runtime?

Comment: you must use tag name to discriminate subtypes?

Comment: you might want to check this https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/230

Comment: Yes, as fields can be changed depending on the root tag type.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia The issue is not serialization of subtypes, but serialization based on the first tag that appears in the XML.

Comment: yes, my point is that in Jackson usually is used the tag name to discriminate between subtypes, but a "field" is added, for example `<Object><type>TypeA</type></Object>`

Comment: Yes, but in this case, we have to integrate with third-party systems and the XML sent to us is without a field of type, only with the different first tag.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use `DEDUCTION` to find the subtype, and so the Root tag name is irrelevant, the only thing is used is the fields:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.DEDUCTION, defaultImpl = DefaultClassToUse.class)
...
```

Comment: Which dependency is this enum?  the JsonTypeInfo.Id has the values NONE, CLASS, MINIMAL_CLASS, NAME, CUSTOM.

Comment: @LucasCosta you can find it here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

Comment: @LucasCosta check this issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/43

Comment: Doesnt works for xml tests. Will put the stack on question.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working something like this:

```
public void testDeserializeXML() throws Exception {

        objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        
        
        String message = "<ClassTypeA>\n" +
                "\t<fieldA>a</fieldA>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeA>";

        TestXml cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);

        message = "<ClassTypeB>\n" +
                "\t<fieldB>b</fieldB>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeB>";

        cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);


    }
```

with

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteDisconnectXML.class, name = "fieldA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteConnectXML.class, name = "fieldB")
})
abstract class TestXml {

}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class TestConcreteDisconnectXML extends TestXml{
    private String fieldA;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class TestConcreteConnectXML extends TestXml {
    private String fieldB;
}
```

Comment: but in this case, not taking the tag into account, in the real world they would have several attributes inside the ClassTypeA object and ClassTypeB object. The FieldA and FieldB values are examples but there could be the case where the FIeldA field inside the ClassTypeB Object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that xml has no root. If you can add root to xml, then you will be able to use this:

```
public void testDeserializeXML() throws Exception {

        objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        
        
        String message = "<root><ClassTypeA>\n" +
                "\t<fieldA>a</fieldA>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeA></root>";

        TestXml cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);

        message = "<root><ClassTypeB>\n" +
                "\t<fieldB>b</fieldB>\n" +
                "</ClassTypeB></root>";

        cxml =   this.objectMapper.readValue(message, TestXml.class);


    }
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteDisconnectXML.class, name = "ClassTypeA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TestConcreteConnectXML.class, name = "ClassTypeB")
})
abstract class TestXml {

}

@Getter
@Setter
class TestConcreteConnectXML extends TestXml {
    private String fieldB;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class TestConcreteDisconnectXML extends TestXml{
    private String fieldA;
}
```

I don't know any solution to have this behavior without root element when using XmlMapper. If you want, you could try to use other XML libraries which are dedicated to XML to achieve this without root element.

Comment: Yes, this solution is in question. I figured I would have a solution where I wouldn't need a change to the input XML. Thanks!